# Ruby on rails in rho studio for mobile application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could u plz help me as m stuck in authentication and validation part of login page where only if block is executed irrespective of the condition and the code is as follows,and login is always successful even though the login and password parameters are wrong.Please help!!!!..
  please provide me any tutorial for string comparison in ruby!!!

### apps/settings/controller.rb

require 'rho'

require 'rho/rhocontroller'

require 'rho/rhoerror'

require 'helpers/browser_helper'

class SettingsController < Rho::RhoController

include BrowserHelper

def index

```
@msg = @params['msg']

render
```

end

def login

```
@msg = @params['msg']

render :action => :login, :back => '/app'
```

end

def login_callback

```
errCode = @params['error_code'].to_i

if errCode == 0

  # run sync if we were successful

  WebView.navigate Rho::RhoConfig.options_path

  SyncEngine.dosync

else

  if errCode == Rho::RhoError::ERR_CUSTOMSYNCSERVER

    @msg = @params['error_message']

  end


  if !@msg || @msg.length == 0   

    @msg = Rho::RhoError.new(errCode).message

  end

  WebView.navigate ( url_for :action => :login, :query => {:msg => @msg} )

end
```

end

def do_login

if @params['login'] and @params['password']

```
#,&login= +@params['login']+&password=+@params['password']

begin

  #SyncEngine.login(@params['login'], @params['password'], (url_for :action =>
```

:login_callback) )

```
 # @response['headers']['Wait-Page'] = 'true'

 # render :action => :wait
```

# rescue Rho::RhoError => e

```
#  @msg = e.message

  result=Rho::AsyncHttp.get(

   :url => "http://localhost/juby/welcome.php",

    )

   @msg=result["body"]

   render :action => :reminder



  rescue Rho::RhoError => e

  @msg = e.message

end
```

else

```
@msg = Rho::RhoError.err_message(Rho::RhoError::ERR_UNATHORIZED) unless @msg &&
```

@msg.length > 4

```
render :action => :login
```

end

end

def logout

```
  SyncEngine.logout


  @msg = "You have been logged out."

  render :action => :login

end

def reset

  render :action => :reset

end

def do_reset

  Rhom::Rhom.database_full_reset

  SyncEngine.dosync

  @msg = "Database has been reset."

  redirect :action => :index, :query => {:msg => @msg}

end

def do_sync

  SyncEngine.dosync

  @msg =  "Sync has been triggered."

  redirect :action => :index, :query => {:msg => @msg}

end
```

end

Comment: Please post us the code snippet of what you have done.